# Using Regex in Java to replace characters with their uppercases

Tags: java, regex

So I found that there is a regular expression for replacing lowercase letters with their uppercases, however it does not seem to be working in java. Is this feature of regex not supported?

```
    String myString = "washington dc";
    String converted = myString.replace("\\b..\\b", "\\U$&");
    System.out.println(converted);
```

outputs
`washington dc`
should ouput `washington DC`

Comment: `String.replace` doesn't use regex but `String.replaceAll` does.

Comment: The functionality via straight `replaceAll()` is not available in java (or most other languages).

Comment: \U, specifically, is not supported - see [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html): "Perl constructs not supported ... \U".

Comment: What character is the uppercase character of a given lowercase character is dependent on the locale, so a conversion from the latter to the former with a simple regex and without specifying a locale might lead to wrong results.

Comment: So even with replaceAll I couldn't achieve this?